# Getting "com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request" in google analytics API in java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-analytics

I am referring the Data Feed Example provided by google Analytics API.

https://code.google.com/p/ga-api-java-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/DataFeedExample.java

i have changed out the variables in here to my own:

```
 // User configurations.
  private static final String USERNAME = "INSERT_YOUR_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN";
  private static final String PASSWORD = "INSERT_YOUR_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD";
  private static final String TABLE_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_TABLE_ID";
```

But still i get the error "com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request" . Through the stack Trace,it tells us that we are using an invalid Table Id. But, the Table id we are using is correct.

Stack Trace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"><error><domain>GData</domain><code>invalidParameter</code><location type="parameter">ids</location><internalReason>Invalid value '80712715'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:[0-9]+'</internalReason></error></errors>
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

PS: Using gdata-analytics-2.1.jar,gdata-analytics-meta-2.1.jar,gdata-core-1.0.jar,google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar,jsr305.jar in eclipse kepler.

Comment: That sample is very old.  Try this one instead https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api.  you want to try to find something using V3 not v2.

Comment: Thnx for the updation. The issue was with the the table_id. i had to prefix "ga". Its working fine now.Will explore more using V3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the problem in the way you are entering your table id. Please note that table id must be entered as *ga:tableid*. Try this and check if it solves your problem.